# Therapy Complication , which tables should store data

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am new to FHIR services , I am trying to find which table should store the complications arising out of Therapy . 
For example in Prostrare cancer , the Therapy "Radical prostatectomy" could lead to complication "Bladder Inflamation" . Which table is appropriate to store this complication , is this Condition or Obervation ? Any pointer on this will be helpful .

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Procedure resource, you'll see that the `complicationDetail` element points to Condition.  The rationale is that generally a complication is something that's ongoing that may require management.  Condition is suited for this purpose.  Observation works for a point-in-time symptom, but that's about it.

Comment: Thank you Lloyd for the pointers ! This is what I was looking for .